# Sending DKIM-signed emails from specific IP with sendmail

Tags: debian, vps, sendmail, dkim

I have a VPS with sendmail installed and configured. I'm hosting several domains on that VPS and recently added a dedicated IP address for one of them.

I created a separate sendmail config file for that domain. When I invoke sendmail with the `-C` option to use this new config everything works great except that the emails aren't signed with DKIM. Actually, it doesn't depend on the config file (and so, the IP) used - even when I try the default config (`-C/etc/mail/sendmail.cf`) the opendkim filter isn't applied.

The man page says:

> -Cfile Use alternate configuration file. Sendmail gives up any enhanced (set-user-ID or set-group-ID) privileges if an alternate configuration file is specified.

So, does that have anything to do with the enhanced privileges? If yes, is there any workaround?

I have the DKIM enabled in my sendmail configs in the following way:

```
INPUT_MAIL_FILTER(`opendkim', `S=inet:8891@localhost')dnl
```

Here are some logs for running sendmail with and without the `-C` option:

- `-C/etc/mail/sendmail.cf` used:

  sendmail output:

  ```
  # sendmail -vt -fsomemail@mydomain.com -C/etc/mail/sendmail.cf < /path/to/mail.txt 
  mygmailaddress@gmail.com... Connecting to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com. via esmtp...
  ... [some output from google] ...
  ```

  /var/log/mail.log:

  ```
  Dec  5 00:06:24 myvps sendmail[6279]: vB556OlG006279: from=somemail@mydomain.com, size=805, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201712050506.vB556OlG006279@myvps>, relay=root@localhost
  Dec  5 00:06:25 myvps sendmail[6279]: STARTTLS=client, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com., version=TLSv1.2, verify=FAIL, cipher=ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305, bits=256/256
  Dec  5 00:06:25 myvps sendmail[6279]: vB556OlG006279: to=mygmailaddress@gmail.com, delay=00:00:01, xdelay=00:00:01, mailer=esmtp, pri=30805, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com. [173.194.205.27], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (OK 1512450385 e185si2018511qkc.351 - gsmtp)
  ```
- no such option:

  sendmail output:

  ```
  # sendmail -vt -fsomemail@mydomain.com < /path/to/mail.txt
  mygmailaddress@gmail.com... Connecting to [127.0.0.1] via relay...
  ... [some output from localhost] ...
  050 <mygmailaddress@gmail.com>... Connecting to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com. via esmtp...
  ... [some output from google] ...
  ```

  /var/log/mail.log:

  ```
  Dec  5 00:08:11 myvps sendmail[6296]: vB558AuH006296: from=somemail@mydomain.com, size=805, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201712050508.vB558AuH006296@myvps>, relay=root@localhost
  Dec  5 00:08:11 myvps sm-mta[6297]: vB558BNE006297: from=<somemail@mydomain.com>, size=910, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201712050508.vB558AuH006296@myvps>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA-v4, relay=localhost [127.0.0.1]
  Dec  5 00:08:11 myvps sm-mta[6297]: vB558BNE006297: Milter insert (1): header: DKIM-Signature:  v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/simple; d=mydomain.com;\n\ts=myvpsmail; t=1512450491;\n\tbh=uGDrXIzqExx4lUFxarebEDLDOoCY8YQTsl6PaOLZSPc=;\n\th=Date:To:Subject:From:List-Unsubscribe:List-Subscribe:List-Help:\n\t From;\n\tb=AzeSIjsaNBKAPe7sma3WwqjytilL4P6b7Yn3mySarov5oWMDrq6wRFbVwexrZOfVv\n\t 8jE1kTNx4kBuJLLEx43WVqpnTxfxupz5FrLYiAADBK8JvDoswOjsIswUN5PNF9Me9G\n\t 8ob+akVOtiNo/A/WwH4hhrT8l4lYQwqnUfEzcihy=
  Dec  5 00:08:11 myvps sm-mta[6297]: STARTTLS=client, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com., version=TLSv1.2, verify=FAIL, cipher=ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305, bits=256/256
  Dec  5 00:08:12 myvps sm-mta[6297]: vB558BNE006297: to=<mygmailaddress@gmail.com>, delay=00:00:01, xdelay=00:00:01, mailer=esmtp, pri=30910, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com. [209.85.201.26], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (OK 1512450492 k44si3222076qtc.439 - gsmtp)
  Dec  5 00:08:12 myvps sendmail[6296]: vB558AuH006296: to=mygmailaddress@gmail.com, ctladdr=somemail@mydomain.com (0/0), delay=00:00:02, xdelay=00:00:01, mailer=relay, pri=30805, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (vB558BNE006297 Message accepted for delivery)
  ```

---

UPD 2017-12-05: For now I've decided to send all mail from the new IP address by adding it to the main config `/etc/mail/sendmail.cf`. If I won't find an acceptable solution I'll move that domain to a dedicated VPS later.

Comment: Since you tested towards a g-mail, access that account and there you can check if you DKIM is actually present.

Comment: Do you rebuild your custom `sendmail.cf` ? If you use `m4` command is  `#m4 sendmail.mc > sendmail.cf`. After this you must restart sendmail process.

Comment: @Overmind Yes, I checked. DKIM is present if don't use the `-C` option and is missing otherwise.

Comment: @2707974 Sure, I've rebuilt configs and restarted sendmail. The problem isn't config-specific, I suppose, because the `-C` option breaks DKIM for exactly the same config, which is used by default.

Comment: Note that if in the etc/mail/sendmail.cf any anonymity-related settings (like redirecting through a proxy) are configured, then DKIM will no longer be parsed.

Comment: @Overmind thanks, but my `/etc/mail/sendmail.cf` doesn't have any redirects and works fine when used by default.

Comment: Based on documentation `-Cfile    -   Use alternate configuration file.  Sendmail re-fuses to run as root if an alternate configuration file is spec-
ified.` Maybe is permision issue. Sendmail do not have permission to use `DKIM`